# Can you transform a *.json file in VS2015

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying out VS2015 with all the new features and I was wondering if I can still apply a tranformation on the project.json or config.json file? Like what we could do with web.config => web.Debug.config and web.Release.config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to David Fowler, this does not exist, and there are no plans to add it:

> @vcsjones: Is there currently, or will there be, anything like XDT transformations for project.json?
>
> @davidfowl: nope
>
> [Source](https://twitter.com/davidfowl/status/542384348679249920)

Answer (score 7):

Just in case someone else comes across this. While you cant do XDT Transformations. With Config.json you can add environment specific configurations.

```
// Setup configuration sources.
var configuration = new Configuration()
    .AddJsonFile("config.json")
    .AddJsonFile($"config.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

if (env.IsEnvironment("Development"))
{
    // This reads the configuration keys from the secret store.
    // For more details on using the user secret store see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532709
    configuration.AddUserSecrets();
}
configuration.AddEnvironmentVariables();
Configuration = configuration;
```

[Asp.Net 5.0 Docs -> Configuration](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/conceptual-overview/aspnet.html#configuration)